# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and : Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am unable to solve these problems and not able to run this hibernate program also any helps. I have written two program of hibernate both errors are same. so i post my annotation hibernate program...

> module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7fc2413d

**Stacktrace**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7fc2413d
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
```

**Customer.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="customers")
    public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="cid")
    private int cid;//P.K
    @Column(name="cname")
    private String cname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="phone")
    private long phone;
    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name="bal")
    private double bal;
    
    // constructor
    // getter setter
    }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jtcindiadb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Pr3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">99</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.jtcindia.hibernate.Customer"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
    package com.jtcindia.hibernate;
    
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
    
    public class HibernateUtil {
        static SessionFactory factory;
        static {
            AnnotationConfiguration cfg=new AnnotationConfiguration();
            cfg=(AnnotationConfiguration)cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        public static SessionFactory setSessionFactory(){
            return factory;
        }
    
    }
```

**Client1.java**

```
    package com.jtcindia.hibernate; 
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    
    public class Client1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Transaction tx=null;
            try {
                SessionFactory sf=HibernateUtil.setSessionFactory();
                Session session=sf.openSession();
                tx=session.beginTransaction();
                Customer cust=new Customer("som","som@jtc",123,"Noida",25000.00);
                session.save(cust);
                tx.commit();
                session.close();
                System.out.println("record inserted");
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(tx!=null)tx.rollback();
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle? Can you share the dependencies specified in pom.xml or build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using an old version of Hibernate on a new Java version for which it hasn't been tested yet. Update your Hibernate version or use an older Java version.